# appium: cannot locate answer button on whatsapp call

Tags: android, appium, whatsapp

I have scenario that some friend call to my device.

When the call starting I have this little window from the upper side of the screen with 2 buttons and one of them is `answer` that I cannot locate using `appium` inspector.
Any chance to click it beside using coordinates ?